# Linux curl request to login into my local wordpress

Tags: bash, shell, curl, command-line

I never dealed with requests before, but I really want to get into it.

I have my own local wordpress installed, where I have this request with this info from LiveHttpHeaders (firefox):

**PS:** I've excluded the data from post content, that was not really needed. Also tried with all the params, still not working.

**POST**

**url:** `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php`

**HTTP Headers:**

```
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost/index.htm
Cookie: wp-settings-time-1=1379163132; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_bbfa5b726c6b7a9cf3cda9370be3ee91=admin%7C1379335932%7Ca34b99198037170f7e76dffd1c6bc1cb; wassup_screen_res=1366%20x%20768; wassup=NjE1ZWM0Yzk4MzczOWYxZTEwZmU4YWY5Y2NlOTkxNzU6OjEzNzkxNjUwNzU6OjEzNjYgeCA3Njg6OjEyNy4wLjAuMTo6dW5rbm93bjo6
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 113
```

**Post Content:**
log=admin&pwd=parola19&wp-submit=Log+In

**I've made this curl in terminal to login:**

```
sudo curl -x POST -d log="admin" -d pwd="parola19" -d wp-submit="Log+In" http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php > /var/www/index.html
```

I get this error from curl: curl: (5) Couldn't resolve proxy 'POST'

**For this command:**

```
sudo curl -d log="admin" -d pwd="parola19" -d wp-submit="Log+In" http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php > /var/www/index.html
```

**I save it to a file, and I get this message on the page from wordpress:**
ERROR: Invalid username. Lost your password?

**Do you guys have any suggestions ?**

**Also this is source of the wordpress login form:**

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="user_login">Username<br />
        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="user_pass">Password<br />
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
    </p>
    <p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"  /> Remember Me</label></p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Log In" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The format for the `-x` option in curl is `-x proxy:port`. You need to add a port for that. And it seems POST is actually not a valid proxy address? Perhaps it shouldn't be there?

```
-x POST
```

Update: Try to use these forms as well. I added some hidden parameters for the submit too.

```
sudo curl -d log="admin" -d pwd="parola19" -d wp-submit="Log In" -d redirect_to="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/" -d testcookie=1 http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php > /var/www/index.html
```

Or

```
sudo curl -d log="admin" -d pwd="parola19" -d wp-submit="Log+In" -d redirect_to="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/" -d testcookie=1 http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php > /var/www/index.html
```

And also try --data-urlencode:

```
sudo curl --data-urlencode log="admin" --data-urlencode pwd="parola19" --data-urlencode wp-submit="Log In" --data-urlencode redirect_to="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/" --data-urlencode testcookie=1 http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php > /var/www/index.html
```

Comment: sorry, I don't get anything in that file.

Comment: nope ... I've tried also without file, but ... it just does the command, with no result

Comment: I've tried your command, but with -X not -x
like this:
curl -X -d log="admin" -d pwd="parola19" -d wp-sumit="Log In" http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php > /var/www/index.html
and I get the wordpress login page

Comment: So is it fixed now? Do you still need to apply `-d redirect_to="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/"` and `-d test_cookie=1`? How about `--data-urlencode`?